# Logic of Sklearn Bernoulli Naive Bayes Classifier when the the predictors are not even binary?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, naive-bayes, bernoulli-distribution

I know the mathematics behind the **Naive Baye's Bernoulli Classifier Algorithm** and it is used to  calculate the probabilistic results. **As we know the Bernoulli Naive Bayes Classifier uses binary predictors(Features)**. The thing I am not getting is `sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB` is giving the result if the predictors are not even binary. The example is taken from the `sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB`[documenatation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB.html).

> - Part(1) :
>   **I am using binary predictors** and I can derive these results by solving the things manually on paper. So know doubt in it.
> - Part(2):
>   **Predictors are no more binary** and the example is given on `sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB` documenatation. **How the Naive Bayes Bernoulli Classifier is implented on it and whats the hidden logic ?**

## Part 1

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB

# binary predictors(Features) for Bernoulli Naive Bayes Classifier
binary_predictors = np.random.randint(2, size = (6,5))
labels = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(6))

# dataframe for pretty look
df = pd.DataFrame(binary_predictors, columns=["X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"])
df["Labels"] = labels
```

**Output**:

```py
X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  Labels
1   0   1   0   0   True
1   0   0   0   1   True
0   0   0   1   1   False
0   1   1   0   1   False
0   0   1   1   0   False
0   0   1   1   1   True
```

```py
# modeling
model = BernoulliNB()
model.fit(boolean_predictors, labels)
print(f"The prediction for [0,0,1,1,1] is : {model.predict(np.array([[0,0,1,1,1]]))}")
```

**Output**:

```
The prediction for [0,0,1,1,1] is : [ True]
```

## Part 2

```py
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.RandomState(1)
X = rng.randint(5, size=(6, 100))
Y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5])
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
clf = BernoulliNB()
clf.fit(X, Y)

print(clf.predict(X[2:3]))
```

**Output**:

```
array([3])
```

Just putting the first 10 features and we can see the features are not binary here .

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
3   4   0   1   3   0   0   1   4   4   1
1   0   2   4   4   0   4   1   4   1   0
2   4   4   0   3   3   0   3   1   0   2
2   2   3   1   4   0   0   3   2   4   1
0   4   0   3   2   4   3   2   4   2   4
3   3   3   3   0   2   3   1   3   2   3
```

**Could someone help me to understand the logic how is it calcuated even though the predictors are not binary. I can calculate the result by using different things:  Multimonial Nave Bayes and Categorical Nave Bayes Classifier. The only thing is how it has impleneted Bernoulli here?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the hood, `BernoulliNB` binarizes the features based on a numeric threshold (default 0.0) given by `self.binarize` (passed into the constructor), so the non-zero features would be treated as identical. So, as you mention, `BernoulliNB` is indeed using binary predictors even if your data is not binarized initially. The binarization operation is performed near the beginning of the `.fit()` method.

The code in question: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2beed5584/sklearn/naive_bayes.py#L919 -- you can look at the `binarize` parameter in the class docstring for an explanation.

Ultimately, this turns out to be a code design issue rather than a statistics issue. So your understanding is correct.